# ¿Cómo mostrar números por consola en la misma posición?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, print

espero te encuentres bien, tengo una duda y la verdad no se si exista pero ¿hay alguna forma de mostrar valores por consola en una misma posición?

Espero que con este ejemplo me puedas entender.

```
>> c:/blabla/pythoncode/blabla
5
10
15
20
15
10
5
0
-5
```

Que en vez de mostrarlos de esa forma los muestre en una misma posición.

Es decir:

```
>> c:/blabla/pythoncode/blabla
5 #Y después el 10 remplaza al 5 en la misma posición de la terminal y así sucesivamente
```

Desconozco si hay alguna manera de de hacer lo que necesito, pero igual me serviría que me dijeras si es que no hay forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto irá tan rápido que solo verás el último, pero imprimirá todos los números en la última posición.

Para ello, me valgo del objeto `stdout` de `sys` y de incluir un caracter de *retorno de carro* al final de la cadena, lo que provoca que el cursor regrese al inicio de la línea.

```
import sys

numeros = [5,10,15,20,15,10,5,0,-5]

for numero in numeros:
    sys.stdout.write("%d   \r" % (numero) )
    sys.stdout.flush()

print('')
print('')
```

Puedes lograr lo mismo con `print` si sustituyes el caracter de nueva línea que pone al final de manera automática:

```
numeros = [5,10,15,20,15,10,5,0,-5]

for numero in numeros:
    print(f"{numero}   \r", end = '')

print('')
print('')
```

Answer (score 1):

También podrías usar las bibliotecas time y os,
mostrar el número:

```
import time,os 

numeros = [5,10,15,20,15,10,5,0,-5]

for x in numeros:
    print(x)
```

Ahora esperar un segundo con la función sleep

```
time.sleep(1)
```

Y por último limpiar la pantalla, en este caso de cmd windows:

```
os.system('cls')
```

Si es linux u otro sistema te toca buscar cual es el comando